# What are the types of keys and values of a string enum?

Tags: typescript, enums

Say, I have a enum like this:

```
export enum Lang {
  eng = '',
  rus = '',
  jap = '',
  chi = '',
}
```

I have a function that accepts a key of that enum and returns its value:

```
function langToFlag(key) {
  return Lang[key];
}
```

**Question**: How do I type the argument and the return value of this function?

I expected something like:

```
function LangToFlag(key: keyof Lang): valueof Lang {
```

...but `keyof` includes all internal `Object` properties and `valueof` does not exist.

Comment: tip: use `const enums` or `as const` instead of `enum`, because they are mutable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
enum Lang {
  eng = '',
  rus = '',
  jap = '',
  chi = '',
}

function langToFlag(key: keyof typeof Lang): Lang {
  return Lang[key];
}

var val = langToFlag("jap");
console.log(val);
```

`Lang` is essentially an object, and as such a key of it would be `keyof typeof Lang`

Comment: > "Lang is essentially an object" -- uhm, but `Lang[key]` is also typed as `Lang`?! How can it be recursive?

Comment: Lang as an object is of type `typeof Lang`, while it's values are of type `Lang`, see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAMghiA5lA3gKClUyC8UDkgPBuA3u4YOe7+ANBlAE5gDOUeRg77uGBfu1TQFZwAOzAoUD3u4UCvu90wBjABYBLIUUAXu4UDPu9wC+aNADMwIaQBd5AexBQANgkQAVUwDFriABQBrYAE8AXFA+fTXSgjT35gQNgbAEpfeCRUGlpgIzBaCzjEAG1-AF0AbjRtNAA3OFooUsshayR7JzhXACI+fkaogulzBlNLYAA6S1NXSvadfUMTcygAE1MAZVMIZIUkAHV5I1kMlxrEWOjfYtN5adRtWYWlzfk1ja2bFwzRi8Xlm8R1ze2Mvrl5UaAA)

Comment: It is not recursive, treat enum as a value and a type simultaneously